# Using own diagnostics in a command line program

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing a command line program witch is intended to open a solution and scan the documents for errors and warnings. I'm using the following code:

```
private static async void testDocument(Document document)
{
    var syntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
    var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();

    var diagnostics = syntaxTree.GetDiagnostics().Concat(semanticModel.GetDiagnostics());
    foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I also want to output warnings detected from diagnostics written by myself. These are located in another project created with the "Diagnostic with Code Fix" template. How can I put these two things together?

Comment: You need to load your DLL into Roslyn's MEF container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `Workspace`, call the [overload](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs#67) that takes a `HostServices`, and pass [your own host](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Host/Mef/MefHostServices.cs#ec5db94da2babda0) that contains the [default assebmlies](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Host/Mef/MefHostServices.cs#399) as well as your own assemblies:

```
MSBuildWorkspace.Create(
    ImmutableDictionary<string, string>.Empty,
    MefHostServices.Create(
        MefHostServices.DefaultAssemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(...))
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm using the 'Roslyn End User Preview'. The namespace `Mef` does not exist in the namespace `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host`. Futhermore the overload of `Workspace.Create` takes `FeaturePack` argument. How can I create a FeaturePack object?

Comment: I don't know; look for static methods or inherited classes.  ILSpy will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the Roslyn CSharp Compiler from Command Line. You can pass the `/analyzer` switch with your own diagnostics dll.